# How to have cell reference as part of argument in google sheet function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How can I include a cell reference and have it evaluated inside the argument of a Google Sheets function? For example:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!E:E,"\*D1\*")
```

In the above example, I want `D1` to be replaced with the value of that cell so that the function becomes something like

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!E:E,"\*blabla\*")
```

If D1 contains "`blabla`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!E:E,"\*"&D1&"\*")
```

Comment: This worked when leaving out the back slashes before the asterisks. Thank you.